# Gzip compression/decompression gap

Tags: python

I am writing in bytes the values of each key of a dictionary called `idf` in a file called `inverted_indexes/id_1.txt`.

To keep track of where to find a specific value in the `inverted_indexes/id_1.txt`, I do have a separate catalog which is a dictionary with the same keys as the `idf` but it's value is a tuple (offset, size).

For example, of of my keys in the catalog is '`world`' and it's value is `(13984, 345)`. So I know I can retrieve values for world in the `inverted_indexes/id_1.txt` just by reading from bytes 13984 to 13984 + 354.

However, when I am testing, there is always a few bytes off. Usually, the offset is often a few bytes too low (less than 10-20 bytes) or too high. Do you know what can be the issue?

**compression:**

```
with open('inverted_indexes/id_1.txt', "wb") as my_file:
        for key in idf:
            with open("global_g.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(key + str(idf[key]) + "\n")
            data = str(idf[key])
            current_offset = my_file.tell()
            compressed_index = gzip.compress(data.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
            current_size = my_file.write(compressed_index)
            current_catalog[key] = (current_offset, current_size)

       jsonFormat = {current_catalog}
       with open(current_catalog_index, "w") as file:
           file.write(json.dumps(jsonFormat))
```

To test, I am opening the inverted index 1 and read bytes from the position 10460 bytes and for a size of 1515 bytes:

```
with gzip.open('inverted_indexes/id_1.txt', "rb") as f:
    f.seek(10460) 
    data = f.read(1515)
    decoded = data.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    with open("when.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(decoded)
```

**Update `idf`:**

```
 for key in idf:
            with open("global_g.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(key + str(idf[key]) + "\n")
```

output:

```
debt[{'AP891220-0082': [134, 637]}, {'AP891012-0094': [498]}]
resulted[{'AP891220-0082': [138]}, {'AP891012-0041': [140]}, {'AP891012-0050': [314]}, {'AP891012-0088': [662]}]
panthers[{'AP891220-0082': [155]}]
```

Comment: How is the dictionary called `idf` being stored in the file called `inverted_indexes/id_1.txt` get there — e.g. what format is in (how was it serialized)?

Comment: Seeking and reading in the file-like object returned by `gzip.open()` are in terms of bytes of compressed data, NOT positions in the actual file. I don't know how you are concluding that the results are "almost correct", there should be no connection whatsoever between what you get, and what was originally written.  You need to seek & read from the file opened normally, and *then* decompress that chunk of data.

Comment: The idf is a dictionary. The key is a term such as 'hello' or 'world'. It's value it's a dictionary, that dictionary key is the document_id such as 'AP_004' or 'AP_9384' and it's value it's a list of int (position in the text such as : (34,57,448). I updated my post